# selenium with python - automated clicking on elements with skipping specific html class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It's just a simple crawler that clicks on elements. It works just fine but I need a last feature - skipping specific html class.

Script gets element then likes it and then go to the next one.
Here is the code:

```
for i in range(len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("upvote"))):
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("upvote")[i].click()
    print("Liked media.")
    time.sleep(8)
```

This for loop finds my desired class "upvote" and then clicks on it. It's correct, but when I already liked some elements, my script likes it again and it's == dislike.
Already liked media has class of "upvote active".

Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

accountActive = "xxxxxx"

driver.get('https://www.example.com/User/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProfile')
time.sleep(3)
print("Trying to login as " + accountActive)

account = driver.find_element_by_id("Email")
account.clear() #clear input
account.send_keys("xxxx")
#elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


passwd = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
passwd.clear() #clear input
passwd.send_keys("xxxx")
passwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print("Login successfull.")
time.sleep(3)


print("Getting xxxx.")
driver.get("https://www.exaple.com/Codes/")
time.sleep(3)


print("xxxx.")
driver.get("https://example.com/Codes?ordering=MostRecent&language=")
time.sleep(3)


j=0
while j<5:
    for i in range(len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("upvote"))):
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("upvote")[i].click()
        print("Liked media.")
        time.sleep(8)

    driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[93].click()
    time.sleep(10)
    j+=1
```

Comment: Shame on you for writing an upvote bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting list with all nodes and then ignore unwanted, you can get list of required nodes only and handle them:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'upvote') and not(contains(@class, 'active'))]"):
    element.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I really like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if element have the `active` class, and if have don't `click`, for this we can use [get_attribute()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method, it will return a string with all classes from element, in your case it will be something like this `upvote active`:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("upvote")[i]
# Click on element only if 'active' class don't exist.
if 'active' not in elem.get_attribute('class'):
    elem.click()
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems correct. I will check it as soon as I reach pc :)